# Achieve external api calls using Spring WebClient and .p12 cert

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-webclient, cacerts

I have .p12 certificate inside my project placed into recources directory. All I want to do is to use this file to make external api calls. So I have read some info about how to achieve this:

```
private WebClient getWebClient() {
  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();

  httpClient.secure(spec -> {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath)), keyStorePass.toCharArray());

    // Set up key manager factory to use key-store
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
    
    spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient()
        .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
        .build());
  });

  return WebClient
      .builder()
      .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
      .build();
}
```

After the external api call I get:

*unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:  unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

Thank you guys in advance for any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to load p12 file via Resource loader API as an alternative approach.